# Can you detect when a dom node's style is set to 'auto'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

With the example CSS:

```
.thing { height: auto }
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="thing">The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.</div>
```

is it possible to detect that the height of .thing is set to 'auto'?

The following methods return values:

```
jQuery('.thing').height()        // n
jQuery('.thing').css('height')   // 'npx'
getComputedStyle(node).height    // 'npx'
```

Is there any method that will tell me that the browser is calculating these values from 'auto'?

Comment: This is probably a valid question on its own, but is there a deeper problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes. Extending the behaviour of CSS3 transitions on the fly to be able to transition from { height: 20px } to { height: auto }, which no browser can currently do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way, but it's not a funny one.  What you have to do is:

1. Loop through all `styletags` and linked stylesheets.
2. Then get the `selectorText` for all `cssRules` in all style tags

   ```
   styletag.sheet.cssRules.selectorText
   ```

   or for IE < 9

   ```
   styletag.styleSheet.cssRules.selectorText
   ```
3. Get all of your elements parents `id`, `class` and `tagName` to find out what possible ways for the tag to get the attribute.
4. Find all possible combinations that point towards your element in your
   list of `cssRules`
5. check those `cssRules` at `cssRules.style.width` if it is auto.

or do it some reverse way and find all `cssRules` with `style.width == 'auto';` either way its not something easy to get without a lot of code

Comment: I feared that might be the answer.

Comment: I think the reverse way is probably more sane, due to the number of possible selectors that could select my div – body > *:first-child, for example – and I don't fancy trying to work out what they all are and then looping to find them.

With the reverse method I would:

1. find all cssRules with width == 'auto'.
2. test the cssRules.selectorText with querySelectorAll and see if my div is selected.
3. work out which of the resulting css selectors is the most important.
4. use that selector's width property.

Needless to say, I really don't fancy doing that :) It might be a little slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.thing').each(function (i,n){
  console.log( $(n).style.height);// if not then just try to simply find the n.style.height
});

//this is another way // at least in ff it would work :)
window.document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.height
```

hope it helps, otherwise you have alot of digging to do :)

For the second option where you see `[0]` means you have to loop as there may be different file names, etc etc...

**full example :**

```
var ss = window.document.styleSheets;
for(i=0;i<ss.length;i++){
    var rules = ss[i].cssRules;
    for(j=0;j<rules.length;j++){//loop style sheets
        var rule = rules[j];
        if(rule.selectorText=='thing'){//loop each stylesheet rule
             console.log(rule.style.height);
              // should return height for everytime height is used with every .thing in any of your stylesheets attached :)
        }
    }
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE**

You must escape those from cross domain.e.g. if you have included 
`<link ....="...jquery.com.../ui.css" />` it will not work as this might be considered as security risk (cross domain)...

Comment: I would recommend you get the last rule.style.height, as that would be the most recent :) aka override the previews ones if any

Comment: It had occurred to me that something like this could be done. Johan Olsson's answer is more robust. It is not just selectorText == 'thing' that I would need to test. Selectors such as body > *:first-child could be affecting my div.

Comment: You could put all that in a function and in effect you can search it as that ... it could look something like jquery `findcss('.thing').height` and you can extend it by using functions that check certain things and you can pick up patterns and it will be alot easier :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient solution, particularly for old IE versions, but it should work pretty well:

1. Measure the height of your element
2. Append some content to the element e.g. `<div style="clear: left; height: 30px">Test</div>`
3. Test the new height, if it has changed your element has height auto
4. Remove the content

Here's my implementation:

```
$.fn.hasAutoHeight = function() {
    if (this.length === 0) return;
    var self = this.first();
    var height = self.css("height");
    var position = self.css("position");

    // Check for inline elements
    if (self.css("display") === "inline" && self.css("float") === "none") {
        var position = self.css("position");
        if (position === "static" || position === "relative") return true;  
    }

    // Quick check to see if a style height is set
    if ($.style(self[0], "height") !== "") return false;

    // Otherwise use the long route
    var test = $('<div style="clear: both; height: 30px">Test</div>');
    self.append(test);
    var hasAutoHeight = self.css("height") !== height;
    test.css("color", "red").remove();
    return hasAutoHeight;
};
```

Notes:

- The 'quick check' line might not work correctly if there is a `height: auto !important;` rule in the CSS, in which case you'd always have to go the long route.
- This is not efficient in terms of DOM interactions so your application would want to cache this result whenever possible.
- I'm reluctant to cache the result internally in the plugin because classes/CSS rules might change and invalidate the result.
- This won't work for elements with no body, such as `<img>` and `<br>`

Comment: Thanks! I like this idea. I'm going to do a little testing with this. The holy grail with this kind of thing is to minimise the number of reflows, and I suspect there are a two or three in this method. I will test if this method reduces the overall number of reflows on top of the code I'm running at the moment (which assumes that ALL possibly auto values must be tested ALL the time).

Although the example in the question refers to height, I was interested in detecting ANY property set to auto. This method could possibly be adapted to width, but not margin or other auto properties.

Comment: After some thought I'm no longer convinced by this method, in terms of DOM interactions there are still a lot, the other solutions might be just as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete implementation of the above suggestions:

```
$("*").data("autoHeight", "false");
var stylesheets = window.document.styleSheets;
for (i=0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    var rules = stylesheets[i].cssRules;
    for (j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        var rule = rules[j];
        var style = rule.style.getPropertyValue("height");
        var auto = !style || style.match(/^\s*auto\s*(!important)?$/);
        $(rule.selectorText).each(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            if (asSpecific(rule.selectorText, $(elem).data("autoHeightSelector"))) {
                $(elem).data("autoHeight", !!auto);
                $(elem).data("autoHeightSelector", rule.selectorText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You'll need to implement `asSpecific(a, b)` which should work out if css selector `a` is at least as specific as selector `b`, e.g. `p#foo a#bar` is more specific than `p.foo`. You also need to take into account the `!important` flag.

This might be useful: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

This should add a data property to each element specifying whether or not it has an auto height style in the CSS, but you'll also need to check the style attribute and think about default styles.